# How to retrieve data from AngularJS CacheFactory to the controller?

Tags: angularjs, cachefactory

I'm struggling working with $cacheFactory, i'm trying to cache a simple GET request and then retrieve it from the controller - but i don't understand how can i do it.

Here is the Service

```
        app.service('usersService', function ($http, $cacheFactory, $q) {

            var cache = $cacheFactory("todoList");
            this.getToDos = function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',

                cache: true
                };

                var data = cache.get("todoList");
                if (!data) {
                $http(req).then(function(payload) {
                    deferred.resolve(payload.data);
                    cache.put("todoList", payload.data);
                }, function(reason) {
                    deferred.reject(reason);
                });
                } else {
                return data;
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            };

        })
```

And here is the controller

```
        app.controller('usersListController', function ($scope, usersService, BookService,  $cacheFactory) {

            function init() {

                $scope.refresh();
                usersService.getToDos();
                var sharedCache = $cacheFactory.get('todoList'); // getting undefined
                console.log(sharedCache);
            }

            init();

        });
```

I guess the problem is that the GET request is asynchronous - so by the time the controller executes the init function - the GET doesn't "get" anything .....

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this one

var sharedCache = $cacheFactory.get('todoList');

to

var cache = $cacheFactory('todoList'); 
cache.get();

Note- Refer this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

Syntax -  $cacheFactory(Key); //get data

Comment: Thanks - the result is empty since the request is asynchronous...but still i have fully understand how to retrieve it from cacheFactory - even went i'm adding data to cacheFactory - i'm getting this object {
  "templates": {
    "id": "templates",
    "size": 1
  },
  "$http": {
    "id": "$http",
    "size": 0
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct, since request is asynchronous by the time

```
var sharedCache = $cacheFactory.get('todoList');
```

is running, your todoList may or may not be set. What you can do is to return a promise from your service.

```
this.getToDos = function() {
            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
                cache: true
            };
            return req;
        };
```

and resolve your promise inside your controller.

```
var promise = usersService.getToDos();
promise.then(function (recieved) {

},
function (error) {

});
```

Comment: NTP - Thanks - i don't think it's the correct syntax for promise - i'm receiving an error of promise is undefined - any way - i still didn't understand where is the caching part comes... and how to use it